# Large, short haired breed in Canadian Winter

Tags: dogs, winter, large-dogs

I have a Presa Canario puppy (fairly large - probably 50-ish lbs by now, 4 months). It's a short haired breed, from Canary Islands near West Africa. I live in Canada.

If it's at least +5 or so outside, she is fine. Anything lower and she is heading back inside even with two sweaters.

For now I can drag her outside to do her business, whether she likes or not. I am concerned about next year when it's going to be -20 Celsius (sub-zero Fahrenheit) outside and she will be 100-ish lbs and I won't be able to manhandle her so easily.

Any tips?

Comment: Are you asking how to keep her warm in the winter?

Comment: How to keep her warm in winter. Or, if that is not doable (we do get sub-zero fahrenheit / -20 celsius) how to exercise her and how to convince her to go out, do her business and come back inside.

Comment: There's a lot of question which ask about cold dogs. Do any of these solve your problem: https://pets.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdogs%5D+cold+is%3Aq

Comment: No, not really. I have an unusual combination - I large powerful dog that does not  like cold. Small dogs are easy to handle, they can go on a newspaper. A 100lbs+ animal that balks at the sight of the leash is a different story.